# Typescript - JSON get value of specific Key in Array

Tags: json, angular, typescript

Need your help to access a specific value of object inside an array.
I would like to display each value of they key hours in the object NumberR.
And display 11am and 7pm in my Angular front.
Json returned by the API:

```
{
    "reservations": {
        "reservationInfo": [
             {
                 "roomStay": {
                      "arrivalDate": "11am"
                 },
                 "WeatherR": {
                      "sound": "cloudy"
                 },
             },
             {
                  "roomStay": {
                      "arrivalDate": "7pm"
                   },
                  "WeatherR": {
                       "sound": "cloudy"
                   },
             }
        ]
    }
}
```

app.component.ts

```
  searchForReservation() {
    alert('hello');
    this.http.get('/api/searchForReservation').subscribe((res) => {
      this.ddataIno = res;
      console.log('MY DATA', this.ddataIno);
      this.unique = this.ddataIno.reservations.reservationInfo.map(
        (e) => e.roomStay.arrivalDate
      );
    });
  }
```

component.html

```
<div class="test">
          <p>Arrival Date:</p><p>{{this.date}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to visualize just the hours, right?

Answer (score 0):

Hi and first of all welcome to the StackOverflow community!

I can suggest you to map the `reservationInfo` and retrieve only the `hours`:

```
searchForReservation() {
    alert('hello');
    this.http.get('/api/searchForReservation').subscribe((res) => {
      this.ddataIno = res;
      console.log('MY DATA', this.ddataIno);
      this.date = res.reservations.reservationInfo.map(
        (e) => e.roomStay.arrivalDate
      );
    });
  }
```

In this way, you are storing the hours inside the `date` (assuming is an array). After that, you can visualize your data doing `ngFor` or you can create different data structures.

Comment: The JSON property changes every time or do you have the same? From your update I see that `NumberR` now is `roomStay`, which one is correct?

Comment: I really sorry to confused you.. The json had been update, please find the last version of the function, I just updated it. Than you again :)

Comment: Plus, I don't understand this error: Parameter 'e' implicitly has an 'any' type. What is this variable 'e' ? I am curious

Comment: The JSON that I posted is sent by my browser, it is not a json file in my project

Comment: @JulienFerrier `e` has implicit type `any`, because you don't specify any type for that response. You should create an interface and use it to specify the response type. Anyway, I update the answer :)

Comment: @SimonLeviev please accept the answer in order to help anyone with the same problem :)